Lua script for coppeliaSim grabber
I want to simulate a grabber that picks up a cube at point A and moves it to point B. I have the grabber and the cube, but the script does not run.
This is the code in the script:
function sysCall_init()
    -- Define handles for the Sawyer robot arm and the cube
    sawyer = sim.getObjectHandle('Sawyer')
    cube = sim.getObjectHandle('Cube')

    -- Define positions for point A and point B
    local posA = {x = 1.0, y = 0.875, z = 0.050}
    local posB = {x = 0.5, y = 2, z = 0.050}

    -- Move the arm to point A
    moveToPosition(posA)

    -- Open gripper and grab cube
    openGripper()
    sim.wait(1)  -- Wait for gripper to open
    grabCube()

    -- Move the arm to point B
    moveToPosition(posB)

    -- Release cube
    releaseCube()
end

function moveToPosition(position)
    -- Calculate joint angles using inverse kinematics
    local jointHandles = {sim.getObjectHandle('joint1'), sim.getObjectHandle('joint2'), sim.getObjectHandle('joint3'), sim.getObjectHandle('joint4'), sim.getObjectHandle('joint5'), sim.getObjectHandle('joint6')}
    local config = sim.getConfigForTipPose(sawyer, jointHandles, 0.1, 10, nil, nil, position)

    -- Set joint positions
    for i = 1, 6 do
        sim.setJointPosition(jointHandles[i], config[i])
    end
end

function openGripper()
    -- Open gripper
    sim.setJointTargetPosition(sim.getObjectHandle('sawyerGrabber'), 0.04)
end

function grabCube()
    -- Attach cube to gripper
    sim.setObjectParent(cube, sim.getObjectHandle('sawyerGrabber'), true)
end

function releaseCube()
    -- Detach cube from gripper
    sim.setObjectParent(cube, -1, true)
end

When I run it I get error message:

And this is my scene hierarchy:

Note: I have never used coppeliaSim nor lua before so please explain as clearly as possible. Thank you.

The editing for the code is a bit wonky for some reason. Probably because of the multitude of 'end's
